# How do i delete all of the content inside 2 certain folders using batch files?

Tags: batch-file

I was recently messing with automating tasks on my computer and i wanted to make a batch file that automatically deletes content inside 2 certain folders.
I tried to delete the content of 2 folders with this batch file:

```
forfiles -p "C:Test1" -s -m *.* /C "cmd /c del @path"
forfiles -p "C:Test2" -s -m *.* /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

That seemed to work, but it only deleted files, not folders, and i was looking to delete everything inside them. I tried an alternative, but still the same outcome:

```
del /s /q "C:Test1\*.*"
del /s /q "C:Test2\*.*"
```

Can someone give me an explanation on how to also delete folders, not only files?

Comment: The `DEL` command DELetes files, the `RD` command Removes Directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

```batch-file
@(For %%G In ("C:\Test1" "C:\Test2") Do @PushD "%%~G" && (RD /S /Q . & PopD)) 2> NUL
```

It uses the `RD` command only, and does it by asking to quietly remove the current directory and all of its subdirectories. You cannot remove a directory if it is the current directory, so the code will make the directory its current directory, using `PushD`, if that is successful, `&&`, the `RD` command is run, using the relative current directory `.`, then it returns to the previously current directory, `PopD`. The `RD` command, whilst it cannot remove the current directory, can still remove everything in it, and does, although it does generate an error message. I have supressed the error messages by redirecting StdErr, `2>` to the `NUL` device.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

To delete a folder you have to use the rd command

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test2" -s -m *.* /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```